# node and react together

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have seen various questions here and answers on the web, but still I can't get an understanding of what's the best way to use react and nodejs/express together, where I use node to serve json content and in general to do tasks such as managing access to services for which i am Oauth-ed. I realize I am probably not grasping something very basic.

I tried (starting from create-react-app) and ended up with two different applications, server and client served on different ports and that's not what I want: besides all CORS issues, it does seem to make sense to share code.

what's the best way to do this? is it to have one or two different applications (on different ports), or how to have a single application serving sometimes json and sometimes react web pages?

Comment: what's best is definitely going to be specific to your needs, though I generally recommend the two app approach. It's still possible to share code between separate apps as long as they share a common root. I believe it promotes a separation between client and server--considering the code that gets executed could be on machines 1000 miles apart (some server, some persons browser)

Comment: thanks azium. though isn't that a pain to handle sessions (like, using client-sessions with node, I would have to do that "by hand" or put all the info i need encrypted in a cookie?)

Comment: yeah cookie / jwt / localStorage.. there are different strategies but if you need something secure, make sure to use tls, and good server side password protection